# Brother Label printer printing Dark image

Tags: image-processing, printing, sdk

I am using Label printer QL-700 from Brother and trying to print a label with image on it.
I am using the following test code :

```
string templatePath = TEMPLATE_DIRECTORY;
            // None decoration frame
            if (cmbTemplate.SelectedIndex == 0)
            {
                templatePath += TEMPLATE_SIMPLE;
            }
            // Decoration frame
            else
            {
                templatePath += TEMPLATE_FRAME;
            }

            bpac.DocumentClass doc = new DocumentClass();
            if (doc.Open(templatePath) != false)
            {
                try
                {
                    //doc.GetObject("objCompany").Text = txtCompany.Text;
                    //doc.GetObject("objName").Text = txtName.Text;

                    // doc.SetMediaById(doc.Printer.GetMediaId(), true);
                    doc.SetPrinter("Brother QL-700", true);
                    bpac.Object ob = doc.GetObject("Photo");
                    //ob.SetData(0, @"C:\Photo\635466380534236711.png", 4);

                    doc.StartPrint("", PrintOptionConstants.bpoDefault);
                    doc.PrintOut(1, PrintOptionConstants.bpoDefault);
                    doc.EndPrint();
                    doc.Close();
                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                { 

}
            }
```

I have a template and at the runtime I set the image. But the thing is its printing the image too dark. Can anybody suggest how can I fix it ?
I tried
- Changing the brightness of the Printer Properties
- Tried changing the Brightness of the image in the Default image on the Template.
Nothing worked.
Anybody, anything - please suggest.

Comment: Does it print correctly on other printers?

Comment: Yes. It does. I tried Dymo printer[another label printer] and its all good there.

Comment: Sounds like an issue with the Brother printer, or its drivers then. Have you contacted their support?

Comment: Hi, I modified a template from "Asset Management" category and saved it as a new templete. It is not working in my C# project. Any idea/help to resolve it